# How to disable text field which is present inside a '<td>', when a button is press from the same row?

Tags: jquery, html

I write this code to make a dynamic table by using jQuery. When i clicked on save button then all the rows input text field is disabled. I need to disable only that input fields from where a save button is pressed. (Every row having its own save button, this is made by jQuery function) please run this code to know more about it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dyanamic Table</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="valid.js">

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    table{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 20px 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>This is Dyanamic Table</h1>
        <button type="button" id="newelement"> Add New Row</button>
        <table border="1" id="createElement" width="500px" height="50px">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" id="click"> click me</button>     
</body>
</html>

 function hello(arr){
         $(arr).hide();
         var row = $(arr).next();
         row.hide();
         var per =  $(arr).prevAll();
         per.show();
         //$(this).parent().prev().find("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', false);
        $("table tr input[type=text]").prop("disabled", true);
        $("table tr input[type=email]").prop("disabled", true);
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var id = 0;
        var mainid =1;
        var nameid = 0;
        var emailid = 0;
        var addButton = 0;
        var cancelid = 0;
        $("#newelement").click(function (){
            var createelement ='<tr><td>'+mainid+'</td> <td><input type="text" placeholder = "name"></td><td><input type="email" placeholder="email"></td> <td><input type="button" value="edit" style="display:none;"> <input type="button" value="save" id = "save'+addButton+'" onclick="hello(this)" ><input type="button" name="first" value="cancel" id="cancel'+cancelid+'"></td></tr>';
            $("table").append(createelement);
            id += 1;
            nameid += 1;
            emailid += 1;
            mainid += 1;
            addButton += 1;
        });
});
```

Comment: After Some modification its working now $(arr).parent().parent().find("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', true);
      $(arr).parent().parent().find("input[type=email]").prop('disabled', true);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use .each() in jquery to be quick

you will be giving that input field a class name in order to style it anyways

```
$("table-class-name  .input-class-name).each(function(){
   $(this).attr("disabled","true");
});
```

You can bind this function to a click event

Comment: You code could be simplified to `$(".table-class-name .input-class-name").prop("disabled", true);`  as it stands it would throw an error as well.

Comment: I suggested using .each()  since there would be multiple input fields and .prop would just be applied to the first object as a row detected in dom by jq @ErikPhilips

Comment: [Sorry but you are mistaken about how jQuery works, each() is not needed.](https://jsfiddle.net/erikphilips/zdjpofh5/2/)